# Postgresql - How to use string_to_array on another column value

Tags: postgresql

How can I use `string_to_array` or `split_part` on another column value.

I want do something like `select * from tenants where id IN (select string_to_array(select ancestry from tenants where id = 39,'/'));`

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------------+----------------------
id                        | 1
domain                    |
subdomain                 |
name                      | My Company
login_text                |
logo_file_name            |
logo_content_type         |
logo_file_size            |
logo_updated_at           |
login_logo_file_name      |
login_logo_content_type   |
login_logo_file_size      |
login_logo_updated_at     |
ancestry                  |
divisible                 | t
description               | Tenant for My Company
use_config_for_attributes | t
default_miq_group_id      | 1
source_type               |
source_id                 |
-[ RECORD 3 ]-------------+----------------------
id                        | 35
domain                    |
subdomain                 |
name                      | Tenant_2
login_text                |
logo_file_name            |
logo_content_type         |
logo_file_size            |
logo_updated_at           |
login_logo_file_name      |
login_logo_content_type   |
login_logo_file_size      |
login_logo_updated_at     |
ancestry                  | 1
divisible                 | t
description               | Tenant_2
use_config_for_attributes | f
default_miq_group_id      | 36
source_type               |
source_id                 |
-[ RECORD 7 ]-------------+----------------------
id                        | 39
domain                    |
subdomain                 |
name                      | Child_Teanant_202
login_text                |
logo_file_name            |
logo_content_type         |
logo_file_size            |
logo_updated_at           |
login_logo_file_name      |
login_logo_content_type   |
login_logo_file_size      |
login_logo_updated_at     |
ancestry                  | 1/35
divisible                 | t
description               | Child_Teanant_202
use_config_for_attributes | f
default_miq_group_id      | 52
source_type               |
source_id                 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to enforce word boundaries:

```
select *
from tenants
where (select ancestry from tenants where id = 39) 
  ~ ('\y' || id || '\y')
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7e60a/1).

Without the word boundaries an id of `1` would match an ancestry of `123`.

Note Postgres's unusual regex for word boundary `\y`, which elsewhere is `\b`.

Comment: I get the following error..


ERROR:  syntax error at or near "rlike"
LINE 4:     from tenants where id = 39) rlike '\y' || id || '\y'

Comment: @john already fixed. Check answer again: use `~` or `similar to`

Comment: The tilde isn't accepted either. 

ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] ~ unknown
LINE 1: ...t array_agg(ancestry) from tenants where id = 39) ~ '\y' || ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Any idea why the string_to_array or split_part doesn't work for this?

Comment: Try new version (I am thumbing this in on a phone btw).  String_to_array creates an array type from a string, like split in many languages, which isn't so useful.

Comment: I want the value `1/35` as 1 and 35 as the ID's for the `select * from tenants where id IN `

Comment: I'm using psql (PostgreSQL) 10.19

Comment: @john the current query works: See linked live demo.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this.

One is to simply unnest the elements of `ancestry`

```
select *
from tenants
where id in (select a.id::int
             from tenants t2
                cross join unnest(string_to_array(t2.ancestry, '/')) as a(id)
             where t2.id = 39);
```

Converting the string to an array in order to be able to use the `= ANY()` operator is a bit tricky, because you need two levels of parentheses plus a type cast to an integer array to make that work:

```
select *
from tenants
where id = any ((select string_to_array(t2.ancestry, '/')
                 from tenants t2
                 where t2.id = 39)::int[]);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=41d6efb6df227554cc6206deba82f9dc)

Comment: That works. Can I ask if I can include the ID 39 itself as well? So it needs to select 1, 35 and 39.

Comment: FYI, I won't be explicitly specifying id to filter, but rather it would be a ID from another query but I want the ID to be part of the filters.